# How to setOnClickListener() on individual tabs in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using TabLayout, which is set up with ViewPager. The ViewPager has a long scrolling list.

**What I want is when I click on a particular Tab, say Feeds, I want my list to scroll to top. But I can't figure out how to set an onClickListener() on Tabs.**

I have used ***setOnTabSelectedListener()*** which works fine, except that it works even when I am swiping between tabs.

[image]

As you can see when I click on any tab, feeds or trending or profile, I need a callback/listener so that I can scroll my list to top, just like in Facebook app, where when you click on top, the entire list will scroll to top.

B/w I know how to scroll to top.

Comment: spec.setIndicator(WHAT ARE YOU PASSING HERE); in your code

Comment: and you don't want to scroll to top when swiping?

Comment: @Zharf Nope, I don't need it while swiping. Only when I click on tabs, I need to scroll to top.

Comment: post your code for helping you

Comment: @ankitagrawal There isn't much. I have a TabLayout variable mTablayout, and it's setup with ViewPager. Now I need to set some kind of onClickListener to detect clicks on Tabs in TabLayout.

Comment: dont use TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

Comment: @ankitagrawal Got the solution, in setOnTabSelectedListener() there is onTabRelected() method. I overrode it, and it worked. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: Looking at the sources of TabLayout, doesn't seem like there's any easy way to do this, it sets OnClickListeners for each TabView internally and all those classes/methods are private

Comment: yes there is onTabReselected method

Comment: how onTAbREselected solved your issue?

Comment: @Zharf Yeah, I also dug little bit inside TabLayout. I tried to get individual tabs using getTabAt(int position) method, but the Tabs extend from Object and not View. So I can't set an onClickListener() to individual tabs. But I found out a solution, using setOnTabSelected() listener, which has onTabRelected() method, which serves my requirement.

Comment: now i get it , i didnt understood what u needed, yes tablayout with onTabReselcted will work like onClick but only when it is already selected tab